# System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001 error in trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, soql

i have soql in Apex trigger where as it is fetching the all the records of test object.
SOQl is fetching more than 50000 records so when ever i am updating the records i am facing this governor limits error .
please let me know how to solve this error.

```
List<test__c> ocrInformation = new List<test__c>();
Map<String,String> Opporgcode=new Map<String,String>();
ocrInformation= [select id,Team__c,Org__c from test__c];//facing an error here
for(test__c oct: ocrInformation){
    Opporgcode.put(oct.Org__c,oct.Team__c);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's standard Salesforce limitation

> total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries = 50,000

Do you really need to select all test__c records? Possibly, you could reduce amount of retrieved data with help op `where` or `limit` conditions. If not, you can try to use [Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm). It allows the 50k limit counts per batch execution.

Comment: Thanks for your information.Is there any way we can increase this 50,000 limit by using any annotation some think like that.Because this is the trigger existed from long and for new enhancement we are getting the more records now.So changing existed logic is not preferable with batch class.

Comment: There is annotation '@ReadOnly' which allows to retrieve to 1 million rows, but you won't be able to make any changes to them. That means, you will not be able to perform DML operations when you execute a transaction. So, if you need to modify the data you should look at using Batch Apex.

Comment: I would add, that you might be allowed (by your busines logic) to filter records by date, or Team__c, or Org__c. I would suggest WHERE clause first.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughts.